# Can I get a pointer/reference to a constant? C#

Tags: c#, pointers, roslyn

**Disclaimer:** This question is out of curiosity only, obviously one should never try to do this.

I understand that constants are not variables. But the value of a constant has to be stored somewhere in memory right? And that memory location has an address. So there must be a way to get that address, right?

Something like this:

```
const int seven = 7;

void Test()
{
    Console.Write(seven);//7
    int* pointerToSeven = GetThePointerOfConstSeven();//here we get the pointer to the constant
    Increment(pointerToSeven);
    Console.Write(seven);//8
}



void Increment(int* value)
{
    (*value)++;
}
```

**Ignoring the fact that this is a stupid thing to do, is there any way to do this in C#?**

Comment: The main answer is no, it isn't possible. That is because the `7` doesn't have to be stored in (data) memory anywhere - it is just referred to directly as a number in the IL and machine code. However, one type of `const` does require storage - a `const string`. Then you can get a `char*` and modify the string.

Comment: This is a good question if you want to understand the language structure. For example, in C++ const keyword just puts a syntactic restrictions on an otherwise regular variable. But in C# it is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main answer is no, it isn't possible. That is because the `7` doesn't have to be stored in (data) memory anywhere - it is just referred to directly as a number in the IL and machine code.

Consider:

```
const int seven = 7;
Console.WriteLine(seven);
```

Which produces IL:

```
IL_0000 ldc.i4.7    
IL_0001 call Console.WriteLine (Int32)
```

Which becomes machine code:

```
L0006   mov [rsp+0x20], rax
L000b   mov ecx, 7
L0010   call    System.Console.WriteLine(Int32)
```

As you can see, the `const int seven` becomes a literal `7` in the code.

However, one type of `const` does require storage - a `const string`. Then you can get a `char*` and modify the string

```
const string sv = "7";

Console.WriteLine(sv); // outputs 7

unsafe {
    fixed (char* p = sv) {
        *p = '8';
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sv); // outputs 8
```

As you noted, this is a **very bad idea**.

Comment: A little bit of testing shows that, at least in debug mode (non-optimized), this does not change the values of `const` strings in not-yet-Jitted methods, here is a fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/kX11XS which does not run because of `unsafe`, you can copy into LinqPad and test it. The bad idea has just got a little worse

Comment: @Charlieface Interestingly, if I run in LINQPad optimized (after adding `Console.WriteLine(test);` as the first line of `ChangeConst`) I get Test,Best,Best but if I run it without optimization, I get Test,Best,Test (!).

Comment: Makes sense, because optimized builds will inline everything, therefore the whole thing is Jitted in one go. At that point, all references point to the same instance. Whereas if it's not Jitted yet then it seems the Jitter can't find a matching string from the intern pool, and creates a new one

Comment: @Charlieface LINQPad shows `Test` as being inlined into `Main` but `ChangeConst` is not. (Yet another gotcha with this - using string interpolation with the constant `test` causes the compiler to just create a new constant string containing the other string and the word "test" :) )

Answer (score 1):

The compiler replaces constants with literals. At runtime, the only place in memory that holds the value of the constant is a variable whose value was assigned from the constant.

Incidentally, the compiler also does this with values that can be computed from constants at compile time. This means you don't gain any efficiency by defining constants for simple arithmetic operations on other constants. For example, there's no runtime difference between defining a constant `HALF_PI` and just writing `Math.PI / 2` everywhere. The reason to define `HALF_PI` would be convenience or readability.